# Posting JSON Data With PHP cURL returns Invalid Content Type error

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm working with [OpenSRS EMAIL API](https://email.opensrs.guide/docs/overview-5). I'm trying to [create a new user email](https://email.opensrs.guide/docs/change_user) for a domain. In their first [example](https://email.opensrs.guide/docs/change_user#examples-for-change_user), they are using JSON format :

```
{
  "credentials": {
        "user": "domain_admin@example.com",
    "password": "sw0rdf1sh"
  },
  "user": "bhayden@example.com",
  "attributes": {
    "name": "Bob Hayden",
    "password": "changeit",
    "delivery_forward": true,
    "forward_recipients": [
        "bob.hayden@example.com
  }
}
```

I'm sending this with cURL

```
$json = array(
"user" => $emailName,
"attributes" => array(
"name" => "Janet User",
"password" => $email_password,
"delivery_forward" => false
)
);
//
//
$payload = json_encode( $json );
//
$data = [
'Content-Type:application/json',
'X-Username:' . $connection_details['reseller_username'],
'X-Signature:' . md5(md5($payload . $connection_details['api_key']) .  $connection_details['api_key']),
];
//
$ch = curl_init($connection_details['api_host_port']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload);
//
$response = curl_exec($ch);
//
//header('Content-type: application/json');
//
echo '<pre>';
echo $response;
echo '</pre>';
```

This print following error

> 0.9 400 0 Invalid Content-Type XCP

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You sure `$connection_details['api_host_port']` is correct URL? If so, try: `var_dump($payload)` and `var_dump($data)` to debug and check if all there looks ok.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by reformarting the entire request. This worked for me

```
$data = array(
"user" => $emailName,
"attributes" => array(
"name" => "Janet User",
"password" => $email_password,
"delivery_forward" => false
)
);

$postdata = json_encode($data);
//
$ch = curl_init($connection_details_email['api_host_port']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r ($result);
```